Nonlinear ODE existence of self-similar solutions
Consider the PDE governing boundary layer flow:
\begin{equation}
\psi_{y}\psi_{xy}-\psi_{x}\psi_{yy}-\nu\psi_{yyy}=0\qquad (1).
\end{equation}
We seek solutions of the form
\begin{align}
f(\eta,x)&=\frac{\psi(x,y)}{U(x)g(x)},\quad\eta=\frac{y}{g(x)}
\end{align}
Under this transformation, the above PDE becomes
\begin{align}
f_{\eta\eta\eta}+\alpha(x)ff_{\eta\eta}+\beta(x)[1-f_{\eta}^{2}]=\frac{U(x)g(x)^{2}}{\nu}\left[f_{\eta}f_{\eta x}-f_{x}f_{\eta\eta}\right] \qquad (2).
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\alpha(x)&=\frac{g(x)}{\nu}\frac{d}{dx}\left[U(x)g(x)\right],\quad \beta(x)=\frac{g(x)^{2}}{\nu}\frac{dU}{dx}
\end{align}
and boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
f=f_{\eta}=0 ~\text{when}~ \eta=0,\qquad f_{\eta}=1~\text{when}~\eta\to\infty 
\end{align}
In order for $f$ to be a self-similar solution, it must be independent of $x$, meaning $f=f(\eta)$. Then the right hand side of (2) vanishes.
If we now substitute $\eta=0$ in (2) and use the boundary conditions, we find $\beta(x)=f_{\eta\eta\eta}(0)=\text{constant}=b$. Then by a straightforward rearrangement
of (2) we get $\alpha(x)=[f_{\eta\eta\eta}-b(1-f_{\eta}^{2})]/[ff_{\eta\eta}]=\text{constant}=b$.
Assuming $f\neq 0$ while $f_{\eta\eta}$ is nonzero.
My question is the following. Assuming that my reasoning above is valid, is it correct to then conclude that $\alpha(x)=a=\text{constant}$ and $\beta(x)=b=\text{constant}$ are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of self similar solutions $f=f(\eta)$?
